# appcelerator - Interactive Notifications

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I use two different events for notification push, first is usernotificationsettings, second is remotenotificationaction when i put category in payload. the probleme is when i use an interactive notification the event remotenotificationaction does not respond, only usernotificationsettings.

first event

> Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener("usernotificationsettings", registerForIOS8Push);

second event for interactive Notifications

> Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('remotenotificationaction', remotenotificationaction);

Comment: Add sample code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two events are very different. The first one will be fired when [registerUserNotificationSettings](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-method-registerUserNotificationSettings) is done. The second one will be fired when the user selects an action from an [interactive notification](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Interactive_Notifications).